# Different Behavior in Node.js and Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, module

In Node.js (ver. 0.12.0 ) I have a class with method defined like this:

In `./constructor.js`:

```
function Pow() {}
Pow.prototype.wow = require("./wow/definition.js");

module.exports = Pow;
```

In `./wow/definition.js`:

```
var Pow = require("../constructor.js");

function wow() {

  return new Pow();
}

module.exports = wow;
```

In `./index.js`:

```
var Pow = require("./constructor.js");
var pow = new Pow();
pow.wow();
```

The last line of `./index.js` throws the following error:

```
object is not a function
    at Pow.wow(./wow/definition.js:5:10)
```

Running the same code in Google Chrome (ver. 45.0.2454.101 64-bit ), which also uses the V8 engine but not the CommonJS require system, does not result in an error:

```js
function Pow() {}
Pow.prototype.wow = wow;

function wow() {

  return new Pow();
}

var pow = new Pow();
pow.wow();
```

Can anyone tell me why, in Nodejs, `require("./constructor.js")` returns a constructor in `./index.js` but a non-constructable object in `./wow/definition.js`?

Comment: don't use circular dependencies!

Comment: @DanielA.White - Unless you're implementing a clone method

Comment: nope, just don't use circular dependencies.

Comment: You're all so smart; tell me *why* it's bad. Seriously, [witchcraft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024940/how-do-i-clone-a-javascript-class-instance)? Is that your argument? Or is there something more substantive than the usual JavaScript lore?

Comment: Circular dependencies are not supported by commonjs (or at least the support is somewhat buggy). So don't use it.

Comment: @slebetman Thank you! I've submitted your comment as the answer below. Please feel free to submit one yourself, if you'd like. I'll mark it as correct and upvote it.

Comment: As it turns out, voodoo and screaming aren't an acceptable answer. ;)

Comment: @user1739757: After googling a bit I found that circular dependency support was added somewhere around 0.14 in order to support the streams module. So it's supported but with caveats - exported properties remain undefined until the require completes. So you need some sort of `init()` method to link the properties of each module to each other later.

Answer (score 0):

As @slebetman mentions in his comment on the original question, [support for circular dependencies in CommonJS, the specification most similar to the implementation of `require()` in NodeJs, is still somewhat buggy](http://wiki.commonjs.org/index.php?search=circular&title=Special%3ASearch&fulltext=Search). So, avoid ciricular dependencies until support for them in NodeJs has been worked out.