# Is it possible to use Object.assign to clone an object with its methods?

Tags: javascript

I want to use `Object.assign` to clone an instance of a class, including any methods along with it. Is it possible to do with just `Object.assign` or should I be using something like lodash `deepClone`?

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 1; 
    this.b = 2;
  }

  add() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
}


const foo1 = new Foo();
console.log(foo1.add());
console.log(foo1.b);


// ? Where did the add go?
const foo2 = Object.assign({}, foo1, { b: 99 });
console.log(foo2.add());
console.log(foo2.b);
```

Example -
http://jsbin.com/dacopazanu/edit?js,console

Comment: From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), The `Object.assign()` method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. And I am unable to find that `add()` is an enumerable or properties. Why don't you just instantiate another `new Foo()` on `foo2` and assign its' `b` to `99`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` only copies *own* *enumerable* properties, which inherited `class` methods are not.

But you wouldn't want to copy those anyway - to [clone an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025595/1048572), you want to create an object that inherits from the same prototype:

```
const foo2 = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo1)), foo1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is, that out of the box, no it's not possible.

Using helpful utility libraries like `lodash` and in particular it's `cloneDeep` method seems to be the sure way to go.