# Clone object created with new in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, clone

I am trying to clone an object created with `new`. The only way I found to do it is:

```
let tmp = Object.create(instance.__proto__);
let obj = Object.assign(tmp, instance);
```

This examples works and does the job, but doesn't look like a proper solution. I was wondering if there is a better way to clone the object created with `new`?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is talking about jQuery, but there is an answer without jQuery that might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43753414/340760

Comment: Yeah, most of the answers there either don't rely on jQuery at all or just use `$.extend`, which was a precursor to `Object.assign` (one of several).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends if you want to make a **deep** or **shallow** clone.

For the simplicity let's assume that you want to create a **shallow** clone as in your code.

Then, you can either use shorter version of the code you provided:

```
let obj = Object.assign({}, instance);
```

Or use [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
let obj = {...instance};
```

Both ways are correct.

Comment: thanks for answer, i think this way you will not have  prototype cloned..

Comment: @BrunoLM: No, nothing in the above will assign `instance`'s prototype to `obj`, nor copy inherited properties from `instance` to `obj`. (You're correct, though, that if an own property refers to an object, both objects will refer to the same target object. That's what pwolaq means by "shallow.")