# Deep merge two class instances

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, merge, instance

How do I properly deep merge (`lodash` like) two **ES6 class instances**?
The resulting object has to be an *actual instance of the same class* and its properties should be a deep merge of the two instances' properties.

Comment: Merge, or clone and merge?

Comment: `lodash` merge merges without cloning so if I stick with the question definition I would say *merge*. But for me it doesn't actually matter, so it can be *clone* as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

Comment: @zero298 I specifically highlighted the difference, please read the question thoroughly. Not a duplicate at all.

Comment: What do you mean by **ES6 class instance**?  They're still Objects at the end of the day.

Comment: @meltedspark In that case, `_.merge(instance1, instance2)` should just work. Merging new property values into it doesn't change `instance1`s prototype.

Comment: @zero298 yes, objects *with constructors* and *methods on prototype*

Comment: And from which class should the resulting object inherit?

Comment: @Bergi what if I'd like to create a new instance?

Comment: @JonasWilms the same class mergees inherit from

Comment: @meltedspark See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025595/1048572, but in general I recommend giving objects a `.clone()` method that does class-specific stuff

Comment: @JonasWilms Sounds like both objects are instance of the same class

Comment: @Bergi this one-liner is what I looked for, thank you: `Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(o1)), merge(o1, o2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

If there is no need to create a new instance, the following will do

```
_.merge(instance1, instance2)
```

This will deep merge `instance2` properties into `instance1` while preserving the prototype.

---

If the merged instance should be a brand new object it is still achievable:

```
let newInstance = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(o1)), _.merge(o1, o2));
```

This will create a new object which is an instance of the same class `o1` is and will deep merge into it the properties of `o1` and `o2`.
This approach, however, has some caveats, for example (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024940/how-do-i-clone-a-javascript-class-instance/16025595#16025595)):

> It's hardly possible if the instance was created with heavy use of
>   closures in the constructor function. We may never now which internal
>   values were set, and how to reproduce such a setup.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash merge did not work for me as is for nested classes. See this test:

```js
class DeepEntity {
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  public id: string;
  public test: string;
}

class Entity {
  public id: string;
  public test: string;
  public deep: DeepEntity;
}

class DeepDto {
  public test: string;
}

class Dto {
  public test: string;
  public deep: DeepDto;
}

const entity = plainToInstance(Entity, {
  id: 'uuid',
  test: 'entity',
  deep: plainToInstance(DeepEntity, {
    id: 'deep-uuid',
    test: 'deep-entity',
  }),
});

const dto = plainToInstance(Dto, {
  id: 'uuid',
  test: 'dto',
  deep: plainToInstance(DeepDto, {
    id: 'deep-uuid',
    test: 'deep-dto',
  }),
});

const merged = merge(entity, dto);

// WNG: The following fails.
expect(merged.deep instanceof DeepEntity).toBe(true);
```

What worked for me was to use `mergeWith` with a customizer like this one:

```js
import { instanceToPlain } from 'class-transformer';
import { isArray, isObjectLike, mergeWith } from 'lodash';

function customizer(objArray, srcArray, key) {
  // NOTE: Cast src to a plain object to prevent lodash from overriding prototypes.
  if (isObjectLike(srcArray) && !isArray(srcArray))
    return mergeWith(
      objArray,
      instanceToPlain(srcArray),
      customizer({ idCustomizers, defaultIdCustomizer }),
    );
}
```