# How to clone class instance in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have instance of class:

```
let i = new I();
```

before adding to array I need clone it, create a copy:

```
arr.push(i);
```

I have tried:

```
Object.assign({}, i)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a JavaScript class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024940/how-do-i-clone-a-javascript-class-instance)

Comment: Shallow clone or deep clone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following code, it should work.

```
 let i = new I();
 //const clone = Object.assign({}, i);
 //arr.push(clone);
 //const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(i));
 //arr.push(clone);
 const clone = Object.create(
      Object.getPrototypeOf(i), 
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(i) 
  );
 arr.push(clone);
```